# I am not able to access tabbarcontroller from appdelegate in swift ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let myVC1 = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    let myVC2 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)
    let controllers = [myVC1,myVC2]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    let firstImage = UIImage(named: "Search")
    let secondImage = UIImage(named: "Search1")
    myVC1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Pie",
        image: firstImage,
        tag: 1)
    myVC2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(
        title: "Pizza",
        image: secondImage,
        tag:2)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
```

A black screen appears whenever I run the app.

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya. No I am using xib

Comment: then get the UITabBarController from Xib

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya. I need the tab bar in all my view. So how can I achieve it?

Comment: I successfully showed up UITabBarController with two viewController using your code(XCode8.2). So there may be problem in another part.

Comment: @Rakesh Mohan.  in App delegate class you declare 
let tabBarController:UITabBarController! then you can access the tabBarController object in all your class by using appdeligate object

Comment: @Satachito. I have checked it. But there is no issues. Please help

Comment: @ Rakesh Mohan Pls paste your xib's source code as text.

Comment: @Satachito I am not getting it

Comment: @Rakesh Mohan Right click the 'ViewController.xib' and select 'Open as' -> 'Source code'

Comment: @Satachito I have two viewcontrollers in which I have just change the background view color when I click on a tab bar menu. This code worked for me earlier but don't know what happened now..

Comment: @Satachito How can I send it? It's too long

Comment: @Rakesh Mohan Edit this question and paste it.

Comment: @Satachito It tried but it says body must be atleast 30 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I think you did not pervoid UIWindow size 
***window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
window?.rootViewController = UITabBarController()***

or you some problem with setting root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add window = UIWindow at the beginning of app Delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: or else there isn't a frame size set. Thats why your getting the black screen.

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
let myVC1 = UIViewController()
let myVC2 = UIViewController()
let controllers = [myVC1,myVC2]
```